# iOS13 AVAssetExportSession error trying to reduce video size on device but not simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avassetexportsession

I am trying to reduce my video size using the following method:

```
func reduceVideoSize(_ originalVideoURL : String, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?) ->()) {

        let VideoFilePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("mergeVideo\(arc4random()%1000)d").appendingPathExtension("mp4").absoluteString
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: VideoFilePath) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: VideoFilePath)
            } catch { }
        }

        let savePathUrl =  URL(string: VideoFilePath)!

        let sourceAsset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: originalVideoURL)! , options: nil)

        let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: sourceAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)!
        assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
        assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl
        assetExport.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in

            switch assetExport.status {
            case AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed:
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    do {
                        let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: savePathUrl, options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
                        //print("MB - \(Double(videoData.count) / (1024.0 * 1024.0))")
                        completion(videoData)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                        completion(nil)
                    }
                })
            case  AVAssetExportSession.Status.failed:
                print("failed \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
            case AVAssetExportSession.Status.cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
            default:
                print("complete")
            }
        }
    }
```

This worked fine prior to iOS 13 and even with iOS 13 is works fine on the simulator but when I try on my device, iPhone 11 Pro Max I get AVAssetExportSession.Status.failed with "The operation could not be completed"

I have tried changing the quality to AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality and High quality but same error.

This function is called from the imagePicker delegate:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let mediaType = info[.mediaType] as? NSString {
        if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie {

            // video
            if let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
                self.mediaHelper.reduceVideoSize(videoURL.absoluteString, completion: { (data) in
                    if data != nil {
                        self.videoData = data
                        self.sideImage = image
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you do AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough?

Comment: Oh, one more idea; I've had trouble with the temporary directory too. Can you try using the Documents directory instead?

Comment: just tried that.  same error.  I notice this is happening when I pick an image from my library and not for images which I record from camera

Comment: Can you show more code? Where is the original video URL coming from? The fact that it is a _string_ is very suspect; you may be forming this URL incorrectly. You should not be using filepath strings _anywhere_ in your code.

Comment: it's coming from the imagePicker.  I'll edit now

Comment: you were right.  I changed the code to use the URL and not string and works fine

Comment: please add that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct